# Upload Files to Google Drive using Live Usb

Tags: linux, live-usb, google-drive

I have a problem, My windows os crashed and is not booting up. I want the files to be backed up before reinstalling the os. I know about linux distros and can run then live through a pendrive and copy my stuff to an external storage, but the problem is i don't have an external hardidisk.

I have a Google Education Drive with unlimited storage,

So my idea is to upload directly my files to google drive (only the important files and photos.)

Is there any software i can directly run in terminal or install in linux (while running in live usb mode) to do the same?

Note: This software should not download the files already present in google drive to my local system while syncing, it should be useful to only upload files to the drive.

Sry, this is my first post in a forum like this.. so forgive my naiveness.

Comment: Assuming that you can read the drive from a live/boot CD, you should be able to just boot the liveCD, mount the drive with the dead windows OS on it, and then use any normal browser (chrome, firefox, whatever) running on the liveCD to copy your files up to google drive.  (This may or may not be easier than `rclone` mentioned below?)

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Live Debian/Ubuntu and [`rclone`](https://rclone.org/), which is already packaged.

But you'd have to reconfigure the drive everytime though so you'll probably want to use a [live distribution with persistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10). Do check the link because now it is a lot easier to set up than it used to be.